# How can I use `mutate_at` for list-columns in a tibble?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tibble

I have a tibble structured like this:

```
df <- 
  tibble(
    x = 1:3, 
    light_93 = list(1:3, 5:7, 18:20),
    light_94 = list(3:5, 9:11, 18:20),
    light_95 = list(5:7, 44:46, 30:32))
```

I want to make multiple new columns, giving the mean of each `light_` column-list. So I want this result:

```
out <- 
  df %>% 
  mutate(light_93_mean = map_dbl(light_93, mean),
         light_94_mean = map_dbl(light_94, mean),
         light_95_mean = map_dbl(light_95, mean))
```

Can I use `mutate_at` to automate this? (I have hundreds of list-columns.) I can't figure out how to make it work in a tibble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the columns to apply in `vars` argument in `mutate_at`, then in each column loop over the `list` with `map` and get the `mean`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>%
     mutate_at(vars(starts_with('light')), 
        list(mean = ~ map_dbl(., mean)))
# A tibble: 3 x 7
#      x light_93  light_94  light_95  light_93_mean light_94_mean light_95_mean
#  <int> <list>    <list>    <list>            <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>
#1     1 <int [3]> <int [3]> <int [3]>             2             4             6
#2     2 <int [3]> <int [3]> <int [3]>             6            10            45
#3     3 <int [3]> <int [3]> <int [3]>            19            19            31
```

---

Or using the `devel` version with `across` and `mutate`

```
df %>% 
     mutate(across(starts_with('light'), ~ map_dbl(., mean), names = "{col}_mean"))
# A tibble: 3 x 7
#      x light_93  light_94  light_95  light_93_mean light_94_mean light_95_mean
#  <int> <list>    <list>    <list>            <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>
#1     1 <int [3]> <int [3]> <int [3]>             2             4             6
#2     2 <int [3]> <int [3]> <int [3]>             6            10            45
#3     3 <int [3]> <int [3]> <int [3]>            19            19            31
```

It is also possible to have different sets of columns with different functions applied

```
df %>% 
    mutate(across(starts_with('light'), ~ map_dbl(., mean), names = "{col}_mean"),
           across(matches('(94|95)$'), ~ map_dbl(., sum), names = "{col}_sum"))
# A tibble: 3 x 9
#      x light_93  light_94  light_95  light_93_mean light_94_mean light_95_mean light_94_sum light_95_sum
#  <int> <list>    <list>    <list>            <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
#1     1 <int [3]> <int [3]> <int [3]>             2             4             6           12           18
#2     2 <int [3]> <int [3]> <int [3]>             6            10            45           30          135
#3     3 <int [3]> <int [3]> <int [3]>            19            19            31           57           93
```

Answer (score 0):

In base R, we can select the columns which starts with `"light"` using `grep` and calculate `mean` of each list and add as new column.

```
cols <- grep('^light', names(df), value = TRUE)
df[paste0(cols, "_mean")] <- lapply(df[cols], function(x) sapply(x, mean))
df

# A tibble: 3 x 7
#      x light_93  light_94  light_95  light_93_mean light_94_mean light_95_mean
#  <int> <list>    <list>    <list>            <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>
#1     1 <int [3]> <int [3]> <int [3]>             2             4             6
#2     2 <int [3]> <int [3]> <int [3]>             6            10            45
 #3    3 <int [3]> <int [3]> <int [3]>            19            19            31
```